# MATLAB suppress command line put of disp() instances in a function

Tags: matlab

In a function, I have a few instances of disp() to help keeping track of the progress of a long computation process.

For example,

```
function myfun(inputs)
    ...
    disp('Step i finished')
    ...
end
```

In some other usage of `myfun`, it is more convenient not having the `disp()` messages. Is there a way to suppress the message 'Step i finished' in command line WITHOUT either adding new code OR using the `eval()` function?

Note: `eval()` is known to be too slow for any serious computation.

Comment: I think that `evalc()` is the only way.

Comment: To my knowledge, `eval()` and `evalc()` should have zero performance impact. Exactly *how* did you test those to come to that conclusion?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Code inside an `eval` or an `evalc` is not accelerated by the JIT (because the evaluated code could change to anything at runtime), so it can affect performance quite a lot.

Comment: @SamRoberts: do you have a link to relevant documentation? I had a suspicion that this would be the claim, but my (admittedly simple) tests indicated otherwise...

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis type `doc eval`, then click "Alternative to the eval function" at the bottom. It's in the section "Why avoid the eval function". Note that this is going to happen if `eval` is called from within a function; I'm not sure what happens exactly if you call `eval` from the command line.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Of course, whether or not that happens, and irrespective of any performance considerations, the main reason to avoid `eval` is to make code easier to maintain and debug.

Comment: @SamRoberts: ...and safer :) Yes, I know, `eval` is a misspelling of `evil`. But the OP's claim was so rigid and inflexible, without any context and supporting evidence, I just *had* to say something :) Moreover, if s/he knows *that* with that level of certainty, then why doesn't s/he know how to do text display properly?

Comment: @SamRoberts: Just out of curiosity: *"MATLAB compiles code the first time you run it to enhance performance for future runs. However, because code in an eval statement can change at run time, it is not compiled"*. The OP indicated that the function of interest will be run both inside and outside of the `eval` during the same session. Doesn't that make a difference, performance wise?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Perhaps it would  - but I'd just be speculating. I don't know.

Comment: Hi all, the official documentation from Matlab recommends users NOT using `eval()`. The page should come up as one of the first serach results. I have experienced a significant performance difference between using `eval()` and not while discretizing a function using a direct loop. If any of you are absolutely interested in the performance of `eval()`, perhaps open up a different question thread, I'll follow up with some test results.

Comment: As for JIT, I have difficulty seeing how JIT can ever work with `eval()`, since the code encapsulated is subject to change over each run. But perhaps passing a function into `eval` is not so bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no mechanism to redirect "`stdout`" in MATLAB. You can capture it with `evalc` and then ignore it, but that also captures (and thus suppresses) all warnings. Also, all the usual objections to using `eval` apply.

If you *insist* then you can use this bad **bad** ***BAD*** hack:

```
disp = @(~) display([]);  %# at the start of the function
```

or, if you *really* don't want to change a single letter in your function, put

```
function disp(~)
```

in a separate M-file on the MATLAB path, and remove its path from the MATLAB path (or remove/rename the file) when you're done.

But really, **the best way is to rewrite your function so that display is optional, and/or the level of display tunable**. For example, like in virtually all of MATLAB's own functions:

```
options = optimset('Display', 'iter-detailed');
[~] = fminsearch(@cos, 3, options);


spparms('spumoni', 2); 
sparse(rand(4)) \ rand(4,1)
```

Comment: "But really, the best way is to rewrite your function so that display is optional" - This line should be displayed bold. :)

Answer (score 3):

A very simple way to implement the ability to turn on/off diagnostic messages like this is to use a utility function `vfprintf`:

```
function vfprintf(verbose, varargin)

if verbose
    fprintf(varargin{:})
else
    % Do nothing
end
```

Then you can set `verbose` to be true or false, and otherwise use the function just like you would `fprintf`. You could do a very similar thing to create a `vdisp` function as well.