# can a matlab function detect if it has been called with semicolon

Tags: matlab, undocumented-behavior

Is there a (possibly undocumented) way to detect whether a function was called by semicolon or is this inherently impossible?

Example:

```
function myfunc()
  if semicolon % <-- how to get this boolean
    disp('semicolon')
  else
    disp('no semicolon')
  end
end

myfunc; % 'semicolon' should be displayed
myfunc % 'no semicolon' should be displayed
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible... Have you looked at using `nargout` to check if any output was requested? It's hard to tell from your question *why* you want to be able to do this check, but the `nargout` option might get you half way there

Comment: This question seems related to yours https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27049017/how-to-determine-if-a-function-was-called-followed-by-a-semicolon have you already taken a look at it ?

Comment: hmmm... @Wolfie I checked nargout, it could work but isn't perfect. Arthur: Thanks, the underlying 'problem' is similar, I would like to suppress some output into the console, while not using varargout/nargout.